# Error using getRange + clear (Google Sheets & GAS)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

When I use `'Page 1!A1:A'` gives error in the script and does not clear all rows of `COLUMN A`.
But when I put `'Page 1!A1:A200'` for example, it works perfectly.

But as the spreadsheet fluctuates in the number of rows, I cannot fix a value on the max quantity.

```
function Testes() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ss.getRange('Page 1!A1:A').clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});
};
```

How to adjust so that this no longer happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function Testes() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Page 1');
  var rg=sh.getRange(1,1,sh.getLastRow(),1).clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});
}
```